# What is the advantage of analog subtractor/summer?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, differential

Why we use opamps like in figure 2 instead of just add or subtract signals from each other as shown in the first figure? Is this choice differ if I apply DC signal instead of AC one? Sorry if this is a trivial question.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuAo6W.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flhfGC.png)</sup>

Comment: You don't always have free access to both terminals of your voltage sources. In the second circuit, note both of them are grounded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that in the full diff amp circuit as shown in your second schematic, each input voltage is separately referenced to ground.  In your top schematic, V5 has to be able to float arbitrarily.  Often you don't get a fully floating voltage source, just a ground-referenced voltage.  In those cases, the top circuit won't work.

Comment: Is this also relevant for DC signals?

Comment: True signals are never DC, but if you mean does this work down to 0 frequency, then yes, it does.

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to connect V5 and V6 in series like that.  For example, consider an audio mixer, which must form the weighted sum of 8 inputs, each of which is available as a voltage with respect to ground.  They cannot be placed in series.

Answer (score 0):

Most sources of signal are referenced to 0V therefore you cannot put them in series (in order to legitimately add or subtract them). However you could use transformers and connect the secondaries in series to achieve the same thing but cost and size dictate that an op-amp will almost always work out to be the preferred choice.

Comment: Thanks! So as I understood this type of circuits are used for references?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: I thought you were talking about connecting one of the inputs to ground for reference but now I understand what you said, so no problem :)